# Is there any software to monitor bandwidth?

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, bandwidth-control

In our organization we have 3 servers that are located at the office and around 20 pc accessing the servers in the warehouse with distance between the pc and the server around 20 km (13 miles).

Our network is slow very slow. Actually I need to know if I need to increase our network bandwidth and to monitor bandwidth taken by each PC.

Is there any software I can use to do that ?

Comment: Then I'd recommend you to look for some literature on the bigger topic networking as there are many possibilities to do bad things if you don't know how to manage the stuff properly.

Comment: This is a real question and neither ambiguous or vague - it shouldn't really have been closed within 2 hours of the user asking it.  Guess we are in the winter of hate now?

Comment: @dunxd We had tossed around the idea of the "Fall/Winter of Professionalism" but that hasn't gone very far.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any decent router or switch (but mostly router) will do.

Given that you say you cover a distance of 20km...

...well, the routers on both ends should be more than happy to analyze your traffic.

Mine do.

You sadly don't say how your network looks, but I can not imagine this running on unmanaged switches only.

Answer (score -1):

In fact you normally don't require any kind of special software to do so. Normal unix tools will just work fine.

I recommend you to log into your router (I assume it's running a unix?) and simply look at the packages / packages count grouped by the source address and you can see what's going on at your network.

But beside of this do you have a 20km long direct connection to your warehouse? Why don't you make things easier and use your normal broadband connection and VPN?

Comment: What possible reason do you have for assuming that either the router or the computers are running *nix?

Comment: Oh dude, why do you assume that "a normal broadband connection" is even feasible? I mean, I just today looked at a 24ghz link for a scenario like that. 3000 USD investment, ONCE. 1.3Gigabit bandwidth for free every month. Please counter that with broadband and a VPN ;) Also he does not even SAY whether this is broadband + VPN - could be, from what he actually posts, or?